# how to save object to session with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, object

i'm using  [this plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) to handle my session, but everytime i save object

```
$.session.set("test",{a: "1",b: "2"})
```

it automatically convert to string "[object,object]", so the object is gone. how is this possible? how can i keep my object and not converted to string? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is using cookie to save the values, in cookie the values are stored as string. You can use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) stringify/parse to handle the case. The JSON object is supported in all modern browsers, for older browsers you need to use json2 as a pollyfil

Convert the object to a string using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$.session.set("test", JSON.stringify({a: "1",b: "2"}))
```

then while reading convert it back using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var obj = JSON.parse($.session.get('test'))
```

Comment: wow thanks! very clear explanation. i've been struggled with this problem for days. thumbs up